# C++ Randomly generated dictionary words will only show words starting with B

Tags: c++

I am writing code for an application that is supposed to get a random word from the dictionary.  I wrote this code that picks a random line from a text file that has 84,000 English words from the dictionary but every time it generates a new word it seems to be only showing me words that begin with B. Any chance anyone might know what is causing this problem? I would like to have it be totally random every time, like one time the program is run it is an L word and the second time its run it is a C word. Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>
 using namespace std;



 int main()
  {

srand(time(NULL));

vector<string> words;
ifstream file("words.txt");
string line;
while (getline(file, line)) words.push_back(line);

cout << words[rand() % words.size()] << endl;

system("pause");

return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Just a tip, `rand()` comes from `<cstdlib>` and not from `<random>`, which includes lots of more modern random number facilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond the other answers about the limitations of `rand()` on various platforms, if you want to use a random number generator, you typically need to provide it with a seed. The way to provide a seed for `rand` is with the `srand` function. The seed mostly just needs to be a value that isn't the same every time the program runs. Very commonly people will use the current time or similar, but reading some bytes from /dev/random or your platform's equivalent is also common. None of these get particularly good randomness, but still better than nothing. Try adding something like `srand(time(0));` before your first call to `rand`. It only needs to be done once and not once per call to `rand`.

If you need real randomness and can use modern c++ you probably want to read through https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random and, in particular, std::uniform_int_distribution.

The code you'd want is something very similar to:

```
std::random_device r;
std::default_random_engine engine(r());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, words.size() -1);
std::cout << words[dist()] << std::endl;
```

Though you can play around with different engines etc. A common random engine that people suggest is `std::mt19937`.

Comment: thank you very much. This helps me and the rand0 instead of randnull actuallly helped everything become more random. it still wont reach z but i now know if i was more serious about this program to use the random_device code u put in the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Common implementations of `rand` (including the one from Microsoft) only return numbers in the range of 0 - 32767.  You need a bigger range than that.  It is also not a very good source of random numbers.

You'll want to use the newer features present in the `<random>` header.  See [this question](/questions/45069219/how-to-succinctly-portably-and-thoroughly-seed-the-mt19937-prng) for examples.